keep adding text and auto-scroll for JavaScript
I am making a website in which it has a auto timer, which adds numbers every second (in js). I added for the timer the id 'timer'. I also want it to auto-scroll but I have not worked on that yet.
I tried to do this:
var timer = document.getElementById('timer')
var time = 1
while (true) do{
    await delay(1000)
    timer.innerHTML = timer.innerHTML + time
    time = time + 1

I also still need to add auto-scroll too

Use the scroll function to scroll to {x, y}. Get the width from the scrollWidth property.


    var timer = document.getElementById('timer')
    var time = 1
    setInterval(() => {
        timer.innerHTML += time;
        time++;
        timer.scroll(timer.scrollWidth,0);
    }, 100);
#timer {
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;      
}
<div id="timer"></div>




it sort of aligns my text but it doesn't auto-scroll or add more

@Sofietarste show your html

Your current approach is not valid JS code, you should use setInterval to acheive the repeated action
You can follow this function:
    function startTimer() {
    var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
    var time = 1;

    setInterval(function() {
        timer.innerHTML = timer.innerHTML + time + " ";
        time = time + 1;
        timer.scrollTop = timer.scrollHeight; // Auto-scroll
    }, 1000);
}

startTimer();

Here is a sample implementation in html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Timer</title>
  <style>
    #timer {
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="timer"></div>

  <script>
    function startTimer() {
      var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
      var time = 1;

      setInterval(function() {
        timer.innerHTML = timer.innerHTML + time + " ";
        time = time + 1;
        timer.scrollTop = timer.scrollHeight; // Auto-scroll
      }, 1000);
    }

    startTimer();
  </script>
</body>

</html>




this doesn't really work for some reason

can you explain your problem in detail?, the autoscroll with incrementing numbers is working in the solution i suggested

auto scroll doesn't happen, and it doesn't add anything. it just doesn't do anything at all
